# How to enable basic access authentication with Buildbot

Tags: buildbot

How do you configure Buildbot to prompt for username/password using [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)?

I can't find anything in Buildbot's documentation that explicitly mentions this. It has a [useHttpHeader](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-statustargets.html#http-based-authentication-by-frontend-server) option, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

My WebStatus config looks like:

```
authz_cfg = authz.Authz(
    auth=auth.BasicAuth([("admin", "password")]),
    useHttpHeader=True,
    gracefulShutdown=False,
    forceBuild='auth',
    forceAllBuilds='auth',
    pingBuilder=False,
    stopBuild=True,
    stopAllBuilds=True,
    cancelPendingBuild=True,
)
c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8010, authz=authz_cfg))
```

I want to deploy a server running Buildbot. Unfortunately, by default, Buildbot gives anonymous users read-access to almost all pages, and I want to block access to bots and strangers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `view = 'auth'`.

Indeed, this is almost impossible to find out via the Buildbot documentation. I'm not even sure where *I* learned that from (just double-checked my `master.cfg`...)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Adding it to my Authz instance does cause Buildbot to "blank out" all the pages for anonymous users, but now I'm not able to login at all.

Comment: Interesting. It works for me. There's an almost "black" front page; with a user/password field + login button in the top right. -- This is Buildbot 0.8.12 (latest), so might be worth checking that version out.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also using 0.8.12. I get a mostly blank front page and login fields, but it doesn't let me login much less prompt me using the basic http auth prompt.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Thnx for the tip btw. This is all I've found `http://docs.buildbot.net/current/relnotes/0.8.9.html?highlight=view%20authz` and `http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.1/WebStatus-Configuration-Parameters.html` ... There should be some kind of documentation for newer versions wich I cannot find.