# Buildbot: how to require authentication for all users?

Tags: buildbot

By default, the Buildbot web interface grants unlimited access to all functionality for anonymous users. With the use of authentication plugins (e.g. [`buildbot.www.auth.UserPasswordAuth`](https://docs.buildbot.net/2.3.1/manual/configuration/www.html#buildbot.www.auth.UserPasswordAuth)), anonymous users can be reduced to read-only access. Is there a way to take this one step further by disallowing access for anonymous users altogether? i.e. Is there a way to require a user to be logged in before they can see anything?

Buildbot version: 2.3.1

I found an old question ([How to enable basic access authentication with Buildbot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34618643/5916915)) that appears to have a solution, but it is only for very old versions of Buildbot.